# Orchard dynamic drop down menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, menu, navigation, orchardcms

I am starting Orchard and I'm wondering how to implement drop down menu that I can dynamicaly change. Basicaly what I want is to be able to create a new page, set it's position in hierarchy and it gets added in the proper position in menu. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with using one of the available hierarchical-menu modules available in the Gallery - [Advanced Menu](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu) for example.
You'll receive a "Navigation" pane in the admin Dashboard, in which you can manage your menu exactly as you said (set position in hierarchy etc.)